# Azure Virtual Machine Provisioning

Tags: azure

Is there a way to determine if a virtual machine was provisioned from an image or the Marketplace within my Azure subscription? Using the portal or GUI?

Some of the virtual machines have the "move" button and others do not. I am trying to determine if the ones that do not are provisioned from Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to determine if a virtual machine was provisioned from an image or from the marketplace directly but your can use Azure CLI or Azure Powershell to get all the information of your VM. You can use also Log Analytics or Cost Analysis to find out on some level.

Also, if the resource groups of the VMs are on different region then you can not move them directly. There is a guide on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-migrate) of how to move the VM on different region.